# Push array inside array with strpos

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an array where the keys are the name of the inputs and the values are the value of the inputs submitted coming from a form. Should look something like this

```
array {
  'qty' => '0',
  'name' => 'No name',
  'qty1' => '1',
  'name1' => 'John Cena'
  'qty2' => '2',
  'name2' => 'You cant see him'
}
```

I use this one to get only the keys that has a character of 1 and 2, in this case **'qty1'** and **'name1'**, **'qty2'** and **'name2'**, and I'm pushing it into an empty array $emptyArray

```
foreach ($inputs as $x => $x_value) {
  if (stripos($x, "1") !== false) {
    array_push($emptyArray, $x_value);
  }
}
```

I expect to get a result of

```
$arr = [
  0 => [1, 'John Cena'],
  1 => [2, 'You cant see him']
];
```

But I get this one :(

```
array(6) {
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["name"]=>
  string(7) "No name"
  ["qty1"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["name1"]=>
  string(9) "John Cena"
  ["qty2"]=>
  string(1) "2"
  ["name2"]=>
  string(16) "You cant see him"
}
```

Comment: You can't expect to have the same keys multiple times in the same array. Such a thing doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @ksjohn lol, just a typo. that should be 0 and 1

Answer (score 1):

```
$limit = count($inputs) / 2;
for ($idx = 0; $idx < $limit; ++$idx) {
    if (array_key_exists('qty'.$idx, $inputs) && array_key_exists('name'.$idx, $inputs)) {
        $arr[] = array($inputs['qty'.$idx], $inputs['name'.$idx]);
    }
}
```

Comment: should I put this for loop inside the foreach?

Comment: Why would you do that ? I used your $inputs array in that loop. No need for a foreach if you know what the keys you are interested in and won't use all the keys.

Comment: I mean my inputs are dynamic theres a part on the front end that when a user click a button it will add another input field and the number on the name of it is incrementing, qty1 qty2 qty3 same as name1 name2 name3

Comment: As long as these keys are still named 'qty' and 'name' followed by their number and there is 'qty' and 'name' keys that you don't use, it will work. That's the reason why I use `count($inputs / 2)` as a maximum for `$idx`.

Comment: im getting undefined input now in qty4 and up because i only have qty1 to 3 on the array that you set to divide into 2. I have 16 items in array, we divide it so it now become 8. seems like i will get this undefined up until to qty8

Comment: I don't understand. Can you append an output of that array to your question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150805/discussion-between-ksjohn-and-s-domeng).